# NA values in matching (R)

Tags: r, matching, na

I've tried to find the positions of `termen_na_sound` in `soundexcodes[,2]`. I've tried this as follows:

```
termen_na_sound_pos <- match(termen_na_sound, as.character(soundexcodes[,2]))
```

But each time, it returns a few NA values. While I've controlled it manually and there is a match! What could be the problem here?

I've tried also `pmatch` and `charmatch` but it's the same problem.

```
as.character(soundexcodes[188:300,2])   
 [1] "accounted"        "accountid"        "accounting"       "accyn"            "achternaam"       "aciditeit"        "acirca"           "ackn"             "acnartno"        
 [10] "acnt"             "acompte"          "acount"           "acrartnu"         "acrpraku"         "acrstapw"         "acstaror"         "act"              "actie"           
 [19] "actiecode"        "actiedatum"       "actief"           "actiekorting"     "actielijst"       "actielijstcode"   "actielijstdatum"  "actielijststap"   "actiereden"      
 [28] "actiestock"       "actieve"          "action"           "actiondttm"       "actionname"       "actions"          "activated"        "activatie"        "activatiecode"   
 [37] "activation"       "active"           "activite"         "activiteit"       "activiteiten"     "activity"         "actn"             "actor"            "actual"          
 [46] "add"              "added"            "adden"            "addition"         "addr"             "address"          "address1"         "address2"         "addressee"       
 [55] "adf"              "adh"              "admi"             "admin"            "admininstratie"   "adr"              "adres"            "adres1"           "adres2"          
 [64] "adreslijn2"       "adreslijn3"       "adresse"          "adressen"         "adresverwerking"  "adresvolledig"    "aeid"             "afadatm"          "afadatp"         
 [73] "afafilnr"         "afakdimp"         "afaktie"          "afartnum"         "afasrtak"         "afastock"         "afchecker"        "afco"             "afd"             
 [82] "afdeling"         "afdelingnaam"     "afdelingnr"       "afdelingschef"    "afdkdafd"         "afdr"             "afdronk"          "afep"             "aff"             
 [91] "affc"             "affcd"            "afgecheckt"       "afgehaald"        "afgehouden"       "afgekeurd"        "afgekorte"        "afgerond"         "afgesl"          
[100] "afgesloten"       "afgevoerd"        "afgewerkt"        "afh"              "afhaalcode"       "afhaaldatum"      "afhaalpremie"     "afhaalptn"        "afhaalpuntnr"    
[109] "afhalen"          "afhaling"         "afhankelijkheden" "afhko"            "afhlpr"
```

> termen_na_sound_nieuw[100:200]
>    [1] "accounted"          "accounting"         "accyn"              "achternaam"         "acirca"             "acrartnu"           "acrpraku"           "acrstapw"           "acstaror"
>        [10] "actie"              "actiecode"          "actief"             "actielijstcode"     "actielijstdatum"    "actielijststap"     "actiereden"         "actiestock"         "action"
>    [19] "activatiecode"      "activite"           "activiteit"         "actual"             "address"            "adf"                "admi"               "admin"              "adreslijn2"
>    [28] "adressen"           "afdeling"           "afdelingnaam"       "afdelingschef"      "afdkdafd"           "affcd"              "afgecheckt"         "afgehaald"          "afgerond"
>    [37] "afgesl"             "afgesloten"         "afgewerkt"          "afhaalpremie"       "afhaalpuntnr"       "afhalen"            "afhaling"           "afhlpr."            "afkorting"
>    [46] "aflading"           "afmeting"           "afpuntdatum"        "afpuntnr"           "afronding"          "afsluitdatum"       "afsluiten"          "afsluiter"          "afsluiting"
>    [55] "afspr"              "afstand"            "after"              "afval"              "afw"                "afw.ibo"            "afwerker"           "afwezigheden"       "afwezigheid"
>    [64] "afwezigheidscode"   "afwezigheidsklasse" "afwijkend"          "afwijziging"        "afwijzing"          "afwijzingsdatum"    "afwklasse"          "afzetten"           "ag's"
>    [73] "agence"             "agf"                "aggregatie"         "aghist"             "agobegda"           "agonkopr"           "akacts1"            "akfartnr"           "akffilnr"
>    [82] "akffkdat"           "akfiartr"           "akfstock"           "aktfiars"           "aktiekorting"       "alartikr"           "alcohol"            "alcoholsterkte"     "alfacode"
>    [91] "alg"                "algemeen"           "algval"             "all"                "allin"              "allocated"          "allowed"            "altijd"             "alvo"
>   [100] "amount"             "analyse"

Comment: Please provide both `termen_na_sound` and `soundexcodes[,2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
match=c()    
for (i in length(termen_na_sound)){
        match<- which(grepl(termen_na_sound[i], as.character(soundexcodes[,2])))}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
termen_na_sound_pos <- which(grepl('terman_na_sound',as.character(soundexcodes[,2])))
```

`grepl` returns logical TRUE/FALSE, and `which` provides the indices where it's `TRUE` .

The drawback to using `match` is not only that it will return `NA` but that it won't do the whole vector.